# Hive: Error while fetching data

Tags: hadoop, hive

I tried to connect to Hive using the below query:

`select * from some-table where yyyy = 2018 and mm = 01 and dd = 05 runs`

The query ran successfully.

After adding one more filter, i.e `string data type`

The following error is generated:

> java.io.IOException:java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.io.DateWritable cannot be cast to
>   org.apache.hadoop.io.Text

Comment: Please, read the following link about _How do I ask a good question?_: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

The error is generated by Serializer-Deserializers.

Root Cause: When you created the table, you probably didn't define the **`STORED AS`** tag. Try to describe your table using **`desc <table name>`** and you may see something like this:

```
| # Storage Information | NULL | NULL | 
| SerDe Library: | org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazy.LazySimpleSerDe | NULL | 
| InputFormat:   | org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcInputFormat    | NULL | 
| OutputFormat:  | org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcOutputFormat   | NULL |
```

Which is not in the good practice. Your SerDes use Lazy Evaluations by default. Create a table using **`STORED AS ORC`** and then try to describe your table and the result may be different this time:

```
| # Storage Information | NULL | NULL | 
| SerDe Library: | org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcSerde        | NULL | 
| InputFormat:   | org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcInputFormat  | NULL | 
| OutputFormat:  | org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcOutputFormat | NULL |
```

Try this and you may be able to resolve the issue.

Comment: Thank you! let me try this.Also I see in your reply that after table is stored as ORC and described the output looks same as before ORC.Just wanted to check which properties needs to be checked to make sure the table is now stored as ORC.

Comment: Also why this error is encountered only on adding 1 more column filter and doesn’t give error when that additional column is removed from filter, if this is issue with stored property of table then it should give same error for the defect statement that I have mentioned in my original question. This is very strange.

Comment: Just notice the SerDe Library output difference in both the highlighted `desc table` values

Comment: I'm giving you an upvote so that you may be able to ask questions in future.